# React Native Square Progress Bar Equivalent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im struggling to find a library for what I'm searching for. I have found libraries in react native for circular progress bar but not square or rounded squares.
https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar
This library is what I am looking for but in React Native, does anybody know a library for what I'm searching for?

Comment: Hi @jake, you find any solution?

Comment: I ended up making a lottie animation and just putting overtop where I needed it